# C Array/Stack/Queue of Arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, stack, queue

I'm quite new to C language and I have the task to create something that holds an array of elements. I need to have Games and in this Games Array/Stack/Queue I should have arrays of moves for a player (int values). What could be the best possible algorithm to implement this? And the easiest way to retrieve them after? Stack is going to be a pain when trying to retrieve them as much as I know. Also if you could give me a hand with writing it for my array since I'm still new and dont know how to create a queue or array of other arrays.

Here is my array so far:

```
int array[MAX]; 
insert(array, 1, 12);
insert(array, 2, 13);
insert(array, 3, 14);

// Methods
// Init the array
void init(int *array)
{
    int idx;
    for (idx =0; idx < MAX ; idx++)
    {
        array [idx] = 0;
    }
}

// Insert into the array
void insert ( int *array , int pos , int num)
{
    int idx;

    for ( idx = MAX -1; idx >= pos ; idx --)
    {
        array [idx] = array [idx -1];
    }
    array [idx] = num;
}
```

Comment: It really depends on how need to add/access/delete elements of your 'collection' of moves.  Your `insert()` appears to be maintaining a list into which a new element is inserted at position `pos` where `pos == 1` is the first element (?) -- moving the existing elements `pos` onwards up by 1.

Answer (score 0):

2-dimensional array in c, for example a table of 10 columns, is:
`int a[][10]`

and then each row, will be equivalent to:

`typedef int row[10]`

and then you use `a[x][y]` to retrieve individual cells.

Or optionally you can create an array of pointers to int, like:

`int *array[NUM_ROWS]`

And then each row, will be equivalent to:

`typedef int *row`

and then you have to malloc() for each row, the number of columns required.